# GPS icon is not active

Tags: javascript, gps, geolocation, ionic-framework

i'm used lenovo android 4.4.2, samsung android 4.4.4, tablet samsung android 4.1.2 to test my application

I'm also used cordova geolocation plugin ($cordovaGeolocation). But the problem is gps icon still not appear/active in the status bar. So, it make my app location is not accurate. To confirm, I'm opened my Google Maps app to see whether the GPS icon is appear or not, the result was the icon was active.

Then, I've try to run my app in iOS, the icon was appeared.

This is my javascript code:

```
    var options = {
        enableHighAccuracy: true,
        maximumAge: 0,
        timeout: 10000
    };

    $cordovaGeolocation.getCurrentPosition(options).then(function (pos) {
        latlong =  { 'lat' : pos.coords.latitude, 'long' : pos.coords.longitude };
        $rootScope.currentLocation = latlong;
    }, function(err) {});
```

I wonder why the gps icon is not appear. If it is because of my android version or my device but I've been used the mauron85-background-geolocation for running background. It does appear the gps icon.

I've done my research about this problem, but it's also cannot fix my problem. 
here -> https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/gps-icon-when-using-geolocation-is-not-active/22426/3

Answer (score 0):

already solved the problem. here is my code

```
.controller('MapCtrl', function ($scope, $state, $cordovaGeolocation, $interval) {

var options = {
    enableHighAccuracy: true,
    maximumAge: 3000,
    timeout: 30000
};

var watchOptions = {
    timeout: 3000,
    enableHighAccuracy: false
};

$cordovaGeolocation.getCurrentPosition(options).then(function (position) {
    var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);

    var mapOptions = {
        center: latLng,
        zoom: 15,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    $scope.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);
    google.maps.event.addListener($scope.map, 'idle', function () {

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: $scope.map,
            position: latLng
        });

        marker.setMap($scope.map);
    });

    $interval(function () {
        $cordovaGeolocation.watchPosition(watchOptions).then(
            null,
            function (err) {
                console.log(err);
            },
            function (position) {
                var lat = position.coords.latitude;
                var long = position.coords.longitude;
                $scope.updateLoc = lat + " " + long;
                $scope.digest();
            });
    }, 10000);


}, function (error) {
    console.log("Could not get location");
});
```

});